# couchbase java how to set the server IP and the username and password

Tags: java, couchbase

I connect to coucbhase on localhost like this:

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create();
```

Now the server is not on my machine anymore, I have to set the server IP and the username and the password, any idea please?

I tried to search online, but I couldn't sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself

Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("here i put the ip");

Answer (score 0):

Note that is if you have multiple nodes (which is recommended in production, at least 3), you should pass in at least two IPs so that if one node is down the other can be used for bootstrap of the SDK:

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("IP1", "IP2");
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("bucketName", "bucketPassword");
```

You'll need the admin password to get a reference to the `ClusterManager` (which can be used for cluster-wide operations like create new buckets, etc...):

```
cluster.clusterManager("adminUsername", "adminPassword");
```